# Too much priming Sugar

Tags: beer, sugar, priming

Okay, how much danger am I in?  I used a Mr Beer kit...and bottling added priming sugar.  Unfortunately I got on the wrong line - having 500ML bottles, I added the priming sugar for 1 liter bottles.  2 and 1/2 teaspoons and it called for only 1 teaspoon.

Answer (score 4):

You could end up with bottle bombs, and even if you are lucky, when opening bottle with much more pressure, you risk gushing.

I would empty all bottles in a fermenter, leave it to ferment dry and bottle again with the right quantity of priming sugar.  I prefer to prime the whole batch in a bottling bucket, then mix it well.  When you prime the whole batch, you do not have to care about bottle sizes.

Comment: Yes.  If you don't do this, your bottles will likely explode.

Comment: Sanitation is important, sanitize all your equipment that will be touching your beer..